# How do I unlock the sewing machine?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I keep seeing on websites like [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com) and [Twitter](http://twitter.com) that you can read **QR codes** with the *sewing machine* in the **Able Sisters** shop. How do you get the Sewing Machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [an article at thonky.com](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/shop-unlock-guide/), you can unlock the QR code machine associated with the sewing machine at the Able Sisters' shop by talking to Sable, who is working at the sewing machine. You have to talk to her each day for ten days in a row. You should then have unlocked the QR code machine.

Comment: cool! Thanks! If I time travel everyday and talk to her, will I still be able to unlock it?

Comment: @JerryRox I'm not sure - according to the Animal Crossing Wiki, after speaking to her for ten days straight, she will allow you to use the QR code machine, which allows you to read QR codes for designs as well as create QR codes for your own designs. There is no mention of time travel, so I'm assuming the answer is yes.